# Categories and Sheaves Kashiwara Schapira Theorem 14.4.5

Tags: category-theory, derived-functors

In the proof of the theorem I have problems understanding why the functor $\operatorname{Hom}_\mathcal{C}$ has a right derived functor, as C is not necessarily a Grothendieck category. Moreover, but very likely directly related to that, I have problems understanding why in the last equation we have $R \operatorname{Hom}_\mathcal{C}(X,R\operatorname{F}(I))= \operatorname{Hom}^\bullet_\mathcal{C}(X,\operatorname{F}(I))$ for any $X\in \tilde{\mathcal{P}}$ and $I$ homotopically injective. It is likely that a solution to one of these two issues immediately solves the other one. Could anyone help?

Comment: You don't need Grothendieck for deriving cats, they just are nicely generated then. Even worse, you often don't even need to have enough injectives or projectives. So depending on the cat, you should be good! In particular as it looks like you got at least homotopically injectives. If you have trouble with a specific functor, construction or definition, I am very happy to help, but to be honest, am a little lazy to chase down the Theorem in Kashiwara (in particular as for derived stuff I prefer "Fourier Mukai Transforms" by Huybrechts and so don't have a Kashiwara at hand).

Comment: Thank you for your comment!

The setup is that we have two abelian categories $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{C}‘$ and an adjoins pair $G:\mathcal{C}\rightarrow\mathcal{C}‘$ and $F:\mathcal{C}‘\rightarrow\mathcal{C}$ where $G$ is left adjoint and $F$ is right adjoint. We assume that $\mathcal{C}‘$ is a Grothendieck category and we assume that $\mathcal{C}$ has small direct sums and small direct sums are exact. Hence it is not clear why $K(\mathcal{C})$ has enough homotopically injectives. How can one see that the right derived functor of $\operatorname{Hom}_\mathcal{C}$ even exists?

Comment: But in your question you do not need any of that, do you? you only consider essential images of homotopically injective objects, so in particular you do not need the RHom as a full bifunctor, but only $\mathrm{RHom}\left(\_,RF\left(I\right)\right)$, whose existence and well definedness is actually verified by that formula after applying adjunction.

Comment: Thank you for your ideas!

How can you see that $”\operatorname{lim}_{X’\rightarrow X, RF(I)\rightarrow Y’}” \operatorname{Hom}^{\bullet\bullet}(X’,Y’)$ exists?

The statement c) of the theorem states that we have $R\operatorname{Hom}_\mathcal{C}(X,RF(Y))= R\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}’}(LG(X),Y)$ functorial in $X\in D(C)$ and $Y\in D(C’)$. So in particular we need to prove that $R\operatorname{Hom}_\mathcal{C}$ exists entirely.

Comment: Not really, the fact that you have in the statement included a injective resolution might solve that. Sadly these things get often swept under the table, but if you can write down that $RF\left(I\right) \to Y$ you do not assume that it exists entirely, you essentially assume that $Y$ comes with an injective resolution!

Comment: Is it possible, that statement c) is not true in this generality?

Comment: What do you mean that there is an injective resolution included in the satetement? The statement of the theorem does not refer to injective resolutions in any way.

Comment: the limit you wrote down in your comment regarding the additional question includes the assumption of an injective resolution existing. again, I do not know the Theorem you are looking at/considering, but in the questions you ask, you always assume an injective resolution, in particular one could just restrict to the full subcat of object that fullfill your assumptions.

Comment: I am sorry for possibly wasting your time, however I think $“\operatorname{colim}_{X‘\rightarrow X,Y\rightarrow Y‘}\operatorname{Hom}_C^{\bullet\bullet}(X‘,Y‘)“$ does not strictly speaking have anything to do with injective resultions (The colimit is taken over all homologisms in $K(C)$). It’s existence is surely implied if one assumes that there exists enough injective resolutions, however it could ad hoc still exist, if there is no such resolution available. Part c) of the theorem states that this colimit exists for ever pair $X,Y$ in $D(C)$ and this is what I want to understand.

Comment: Or do you just mean that my interpretation of the statement of part c) is just too strong? However I really doubt that, as there are many places in the book, where the existence of the derived functor is assumed but not the existence of enough injective resolutions.

Comment: I think this statement, the one with the double complexes, has itself nothing to do with deriving or injective resolutions, it just tells you that if you have any resolution the colimit of the resulting bicomplex is welldefined, which, to be honest, is quite strong, but it does not imply anything about the derived functor. However, it kinda leads the way to it, it more or less shows that you should be able to replace objects by resolutions as long as you dont change the cohomology and remember a weak equivalence to your resolution

Comment: This statement is the definition of the derived functor in Schapira Kashiwara.

Comment: Oh that is smart, and makes sense, you kinda circumvent needing to assume having a nice resolution and as soon as you have it you can compute it. Really need to read that again. Thank you